# Query Member of (AD) with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a simple menu that lets you select tasks to perform against a user in Active Directory. One of the tasks I want to perform is to display the users group membership. To do this i'm using the below code. My issue, is that in the DO section, option 3, which displays group membership, the output seems to be blank when you go through the menu. If I run ONLY the selection of code from that option, it works just fine.

```
function Show-Menu
{
    param (
        [string]$Title = 'My Menu'
    )
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "================ $Title ================"

    Write-Host "1: Unlock User"
    Write-Host "2: Disable User"
    Write-Host "3: Show Groups"
    Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to quit."
}


cls

#User Lookup
write-host 'First, lets look up the user you want to work with'
$user = Read-Host 'Enter the name of the user you want to search for!'
$w = "*"
$search = $w + $user + $w
Get-ADUser -F 'name -like $search' | FT SamAccountName -A

#User Selection
$target_user = Read-Host 'Which user do you want to work with?'
cls

do
 {
     Show-Menu
     $selection = Read-Host "Please make a selection"
     switch ($selection)
     {
           '1' {unlock-ADAccount -Identity $target_user} 
           '2' {Disabled-ADAccount -Identity $target_user} 
           '3' {Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $target_user | select name} 

     }
     pause
 }
 until ($selection -eq 'q')
 clear
```

Answer (score 0):

If you stop the script, you will see the output of your invocations of option 3.

The following works:

```
'3' {Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $target_user | select name | Out-Host }
```

or somewhat suprisingly

```
'3' {Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $target_user | select name | ft }
```

The problem is that select-object writes to `stdout` and `pause` writes to console, which are two different and conflicting outputs (if `stdout` goes to console). The GroupMembership cmdlet produces output to `stdout` but Powershell buffers `stdout` because it has detected output to the console through `Show-Menu`. Probably it will first show a couple of KiB of direct mode console output before it shows indirect output to console through `stdout` writing. Or it will show the `stdout` buffered output when the script finishes and it kills the direct output to console buffer, and flushes the `stdout` writes.

So, the solution here is to write directly to `Host` yourself. Of course this has the disadvantage of not being able to redirect the output on `stdout` stream to another script.

[A similar discussion on SpiceWorks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1976663-powershell-output-doesn-t-show-until-script-ends)